# tableadapter autogenerated method query will not work in C#

Tags: c#, sql, tableadapter

I have an app that uses C# and an access DB.  I am stuck while trying to make an update query.  I keep getting an error saying the querybuilder autogenerated method will not accept 10 overloads.  i built the query for the whole table and have initialized the variables and linked them to the text boxes on the form detail view.  the user is to insert the new values and the button clicked and the update method run with the input arguments from the form, however the method will not be accepted the error says that the method will not accept 10 overloads. any ideas....thanks

```
 private void update_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string id, fn, ln, address, phone, grade;
        string score1, score2, score3, avg;
        id = student_IDTextBox.Text;
        fn = student_FirstNameTextBox.Text;
        ln = student_LastNameTextBox.Text;
        address = student_AddressTextBox.Text;
        phone = student_PhoneTextBox.Text;
        grade = student_GradeTextBox.Text;
        score1 = student_Score1TextBox.Text;
        score2 = student_Score2TextBox.Text;
        score3 = student_Score2TextBox.Text;
        avg = student_GradeTextBox.Text;

        studentTableAdapter.UpdateStudent  (id, fn, ln, address, phone, grade,
         score1, score2, score3, avg);
```

Comment: Does your method UpdateStudent have a signature of 10 parameters of type string?

Comment: score1 = student_Score1TextBox.   ;
            score2 = student_Score2TextBox.Text;
            score3 = student_Score2TextBox.Text;
            avg = student_GradeTextBox.Text;        I have corrected them to decimal values instead of Text what identifier should i use.  i did make sure the methad was now correct but it still gives me the same error

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment due to reputation, but I believe we'll need more information than what you've provided.  For example what the properties are of the Student table.  Have you tried F12 on the UpdateStudent function to get a list of parameters expected and the overloads?

Additionally, intellisense should give you some information as to which parameters expect what type of object.  If I were to make a guess, it's that your number looking values Id, grade, score1-3, and avg are expected in a number format, not a string format.